# Replicate command prompt with batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am attempting to replicate the command prompt using batch files. My current code is reproduced below.

```bat
@echo off
title Command Prompt
:LOOP
set /p COMMAND="%CD%>"
title Command Prompt - %COMMAND%
call %COMMAND%
echo.
title Command Prompt
goto LOOP
```

However, I have one issue. If I'm calling a program (such as `gpedit.msc`), the batch file waits until the program returns before continuing, when a normal command prompt returns without waiting for the program to return.

How do I test if a command is a program, so I can use the `start` command?

Comment: This won't be possible with CMD alone. Whether CMD will wait or not wait for a program to finish, is determined whether a program is GUI-based or a text-based. e.g.: `notepad.exe` vs `chkdsk.exe`. And CMD doesn't provide an command to detect this.

Comment: @Jay That's disappointing. Thanks though.

Comment: Well, there *is* a way, a hard one. Which is to parse the EXE file's header (PE file format's header) to check if it's a GUI or text program. You can do this using a VBScript as a helper that read the EXE binary (manually, at byte level) and report the result. You can also do it using `DEBUG.EXE` script, but this is more troublesome.

Comment: You could search the executable for `user32.dll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search the executable for `user32.dll`.

```
@echo off
title Command Prompt
:LOOP
    set /p COMMAND="%CD%>"
    title Command Prompt - %COMMAND%

    call :is_gui %COMMAND%
    if errorlevel 1 (
        call %COMMAND%
    ) else (
        start "" %COMMAND%
    )

    echo.
    title Command Prompt
    goto LOOP

:is_gui app_name
    set app_name=%~1
    set file_app=

    rem Get path of application
    if exist "%app_name%" (
        set file_app=%app_name%
    ) else (
        rem Lookup path of app
        for %%P in (%PATHEXT%) do (
          for %%I in (%1 %1%%P) do (
            if exist "%%~$PATH:I" (
              set file_app=%%~$PATH:I
              goto continue
            )
          )
        )
    )
    :continue
    if "%file_app%"=="" exit /b 1
    find /i "user32.dll" < "%file_app%" >nul 2>&1
    exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Comment: I wonder if this is a reliable check... In any event, the idea is very interesting!

Comment: It's not perfect. For example if the gui code is loaded via another dll.

I checked python.exe which can create a gui using tk. My script can't find `user32.dll`. If it recursivly searched dlls it would improve. But that's overkill for this.

`python.exe --> tk85.dll --> user32.dll`

Comment: In normal cmd.exe, does the control actually return to cmd directly after Python is invoked (without `start`)?

Comment: Nope, python has access to stdin and stdout. There is a second executable `pythonw.exe` for that.

Comment: Then, since there's no `user32.dll` in `python.exe`, your script would be running it without `start` and the behaviour would be the same as in real CMD, right? It's no problem then (if I understand the situation correctly).

Comment: Correct and pythonw disconnects on it's own.

Comment: This is not reliable check. For example - Far Manager. Its executable **is** linked to user32.dll, but it is console application, not gui.

Comment: A second search for `WriteConsole` would make it a little more reliable.  Some programs that spawn their own debug cmd window would probably confuse it.